# Why is my Set printed as empty in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, set, output

I can't print a Set in Node.js ! What am I missing ?

```
console.log(new Set(['a', 'b']));
```

Output:

```
Set {}
```

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT:**

I'm in an async function, you think that's why ?

**EDIT 2:**

Doesn't work in regular function either

```
console.log(new Set(['a', 'b']).size);
```

gives 2

Comment: What node version erq you using? I just tried it on v9.1.0 and got ```Set { 'a', 'b' }```

Comment: In node 7.10 works too

Comment: It works in REPL too -- https://repl.it/repls/CostlyZigzagLocus.

Comment: works fine in my case. Please describe more detail.

Comment: This is really weird. In a .js file where I only log the set, that works, I have `Set { 'a', 'b' }`. But in the middle of my "real" program it doesn't